# For which complex values of $s$ does $\left\{n^{−s}\right\}$ belong to $l^2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Would I be correct in saying that for all s in R the values s<=0 hold? and if so does it hold for all s in C?

For which values of $s \in \mathbb{C}$ does $\left\{n^{−s}\right\}$ belong to $l^2$?

with
$$l^2=\left\{x=(x_n)_{n\geq1} : x_n \in \mathbb{C} \,\text{and} \, \sum_{n\geq1}|x_n|^2 < \infty\right\}$$

Comment: Why am I not told there I an edit pending when I _begin_ doing my edit? Wh do I have to spend, waste, 5 minutes editing before being told?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to have
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\left|\frac1{n^s}\right|^2=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n^{2\Re s}}<\infty .\tag1
$$ This is true if and only if $2\Re s>1$ that is for all complex numbers $s$ such that
$$
\Re s>\frac12.
$$

Comment: thanks for such a clear answer, much appreciated